# I have a blue card and titre de sejour in France. I didn't live and work in France for 2 years now. Can I still return and work legally there?

Tags: visa, immigration, france

I moved to France with the blue card, then received the titre de sejour valid for 4 years. My employment contract was terminated during the first year and I returned to my home country. The titre de sejour is still valid though. Can I come back to France and work there legally with this titre?